# Matrix equation with transpose

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

How can I solve this matrix equation for $X$:
$$
(A^T)X = B(X-Y)C,
$$
where $A^T$ is the transpose of $A$.

Here, all matrices are small (e.g., $2\times2$). I am especially interested in the following two cases: (a) $Y$ is the matrix with all entries having the value 2, and (b) $Y=2I$, where $I$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: Solve the equation for what?

Comment: For X , i mean  Find X

Comment: You need to give dimensions. The question needs to be written more clearly.

Comment: All matrix are 2x2

Comment: What does $X-2$ mean? Are the matrices invertible?

Comment: yes they are invertible

Comment: What does 'find $X A^T = A^T$ mean? (Extracting the meaning bit by bit is rather tiresome.)

Comment: @copper.hat Had you gone to the source, you would've seen the line break. I agree you shouldn't have to do that, but telling someone that line breaks are a bit special on this site and helping them with the formatting is better than playing dumb and assuming they meant to write exactly what is rendered.

Comment: @Arthur: What do you mean by 'Had you gone to the source'? What line break are you talking about? How am I playing dumb? I have to say, MSE interactions often leave me scratching my head.

Comment: @copper.hat So you didn't even bother to click the "edit" button to see if that clarified anything? OK, then you weren't playing dumb, you were just unobservant. What he said wasn't "find X A^T=A transpose", it was "find X" on one line and "A^T=A transpose" on the next. So in the source text that made perfect sense.

Comment: @ManuelSebastianRios: Note that the system above may not have a solution, for example take $A=B=C = I$.

Comment: @Arthur: Lighten up. I try to help out where when I get a chance, I don't spend time debugging MathJax. Your insinuation of my being lazy is unwarranted and not appreciated.

Comment: @copper.hat You're right. I'm sorry. I enjoy correcting Jax, so clicking the "edit" button whenever a question isn't perfectly formatted is something I do almost automatically. I guess I just assume that every regular on this site has the exact same approach as I do.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Clicking the "edit" button allows you to see and edit what in computer science is commonly referred to as "the source (code / text)".

Comment: @Arthur, I'm sorry, I meant to say that in my attempt to find the original source, I clicked on "edited ?? mins ago" (instead of "edit").  What is shown is "find X A^T = A transpose" on one line.  However, if you clicked on "source," you would see the text on two lines.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes, that "see what was changed"-functionality is not exactly perfect.

Answer (score 3):

If $B$ is invertible, or if both $A$ and $C$ are invertible, then this can be easily converted to a [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation), and you can use standard direct methods for solving it. If not (or if your matrices are not amenable to direct factorizations and you want to use an iterative method instead), then read on; the problem becomes very interesting.

You can use the relationship between [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_%28mathematics%29), $\text{vec}(\cdot)$, and the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), $\otimes$, to set up a meta-matrix representing the linear system for the vectorization of $X$. In general, the following useful facts hold for any matrices $U,V,W$ of the appropriate size and invertibility so that the equations make sense,
$$\text{vec}(UVW) = (W^T \otimes U) \text{vec}(V),$$
$$(U \otimes V)^{-1} = (U^{-1} \otimes V^{-1}),$$
$$(U \otimes V)^T = (U^T \otimes V^T)$$
$$(U \otimes V)(Z \otimes Q) = (UZ) \otimes (VQ)$$
We can use this in our situation as follows,
\begin{align}
A^T X &= B(X-Y)C \\
\text{vec}(A^T X) &= \text{vec}(B (X - Y)C), \\
(I \otimes A^T) \text{vec}(X) &= (C^T \otimes B) \text{vec}(X) - (C^T \otimes B)\text{vec}(Y), \\
(\underbrace{I \otimes A^T}_{M_1} - \underbrace{C^T \otimes B}_{M_2})\underbrace{\text{vec}(X)}_{x} &= - \underbrace{(C^T \otimes B)}_{M_2}\underbrace{\text{vec}(Y)}_{y}
\end{align}
which yields the following system of the general form 
$$(M_1 - M_2)x=-M_2 y.$$
In the case where these matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ are square and $M_1+M_2$ is invertible, and the sizes are not too large, you can directly form the matrices and solve for the vector of entries in the desired matrix, $x = \text{vec}(X)$. E.g., see the following Matlab code,

```
A = randn(5,5); B = randn(5,5); C = randn(3,3); Y = randn(5,3);

M1 = kron(eye(3),A');
M2 = kron(C',B);
b = -reshape(B*Y*C, [],1); % = -M2*y
x = (M1-M2)\b;
X = reshape(x,5,3);
norm(A'*X - B*(X-Y)*C) % returns machine zero
```

But what if the matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ are not square? If $A$ is a tall matrix, then $M_1-M_2$ is a wide matrix. Unless we are particularly unlucky, this matrix will have full column rank, so we can still find a solution (one of many) by solving the normal equations,
$$(M_1 - M_2)^T(M_1 - M_2)x = -(M_1 - M_2)M_2 y,$$ 
or if you like, the slightly regularized version,
$$\left((M_1 - M_2)^T(M_1 - M_2) + \epsilon I \right)x = -(M_1 - M_2)M_2 y.$$ 
For example,

```
A = randn(5,3); B = randn(3,5); C = randn(4,4); Y = randn(5,4);

M1 = kron(eye(4),A');
M2 = kron(C',B);
b = -reshape(B*Y*C, [],1); % = -M2*y
epsilon=1e-7;
x = ((M1-M2)'*(M1-M2) + epsilon*eye(numel(Y)))\((M1-M2)'*b);
X = reshape(x,size(Y));
norm(A'*X - B*(X-Y)*C) % returns error on the order of epsilon
```

If $A$ is a wide matrix, then there is generally no solution to the equations, unless we get particularly lucky.

In the special case (a) where $Y=2 \mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T$ is the matrix of all 2's, the right hand side takes the form,
$$y = (C^T \otimes B)\text{vec}\left(2\mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T\right) = 2\text{vec}\left(B \mathbb{1}\mathbb{1}^T C\right) =  2\text{vec}\left((B \mathbb{1})(C^T \mathbb{1})^T\right),$$
where $\mathbb{1}$ is the vector of all ones.

In the special case (b) where $Y=2I$, the right hand side takes the form,
$$y = (C^T \otimes B)\text{vec}\left(2I\right) = 2\text{vec}(BIC) = 2\text{vec}(BC)$$

If the problem is large enough that forming $M$ is prohibitive, you can still apply the action of $M_1$ and $M_2$ on a vector $u=\text{vec}(U)$ by doing some matrix multiplications,
$$M_1u = \text{vec}(A^T U), \quad M_2u = \text{vec}(BUC),$$
which allows you to use iterative methods like [GMRES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_minimal_residual_method). Furthermore, we can precondition it as follows: if one of the matrices $M_1$ or $M_2$ is dominant over the other, you can use that matrix as a preconditioner.

If both matrices are of roughly equal importance, then you [use both together](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10882/is-there-any-way-to-do-double-preconditioning) as preconditioners, either additively, or multiplicatively.

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you explain what $X-2$ means?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche In matrix equations, a number $r$ is often used as shorthand for $rI$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. This is a slight abuse of notation, but common enough.

Comment: @Arthur, thanks.  I was unfamiliar with that notation.

Comment: Usually in the context of matrix equations, $X-2$ means subtracting the matrix of all 2's (not the identity). This is somewhat confusing but this is how I have seen it in this context.

Comment: @NickAlger, thanks, I'm also unfamiliar with that practice.

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche the abuse not so bad if it's part of a parenthesis, like here. If you use the distributive law on $(X-2)C$, then the end result, $XC-2C$, makes perfect sense, as long as the dimensions match. This, along with the fact that in the ring of square $n\times n$ matrices, the identity matrix is truly the unit, is probably the reason why many feel it's OK to write something like that. I was unaware of the other practice.